# Parse-server Cloud Code Error 141 Invalid Function

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, parse-server

I am running parse-server on Heroku, I am working on implementing a custom cloud code function, however every implementation returns invalid function code: 141, Version:1.12.0

I have successfully gotten the "hello" function to work, including 1 change I made to it:

```js
Parse.Cloud.define('hello', function(req, res) {
  console.log("received.........");
  res.success('Hi');
});
```

The custom function I am trying to get working is a simple query to my database:

```js
Parse.Cloud.define("titleQuery", function(request, response) {
  var query = new Parse.Query("StudentNotes");
  query.equalTo("title", request.params.title);
  query.find({
    success: function(results) {

      console.log("received........." + results);

      response.success(results);
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log("received........." + error);

      response.error("title lookup failed");
    }
  });
});
```

When I run this on iOS with the following code:

```js
        PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("titleQuery", withParameters: ["title": "testTitle"]) {
          (response: AnyObject ? , error : NSError ? ) - > Void in
            let hello = response // as? String
          print(hello)

        }
```

I am querying my database in class "StudentNotes" for object title with the name "testTitle", I know for a fact that that object exists, however due to it throwing error 141 I do not receive anything.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT2: I have gotten custom cloud functions to work, however I cannot get any queries to my database to work.  **Can anyone post a confirmed working query that returns an object?  Perhaps from the _User table so that I can copy/paste and ensure that my cloud code can access my database?**

My process:
I edit the Main.js file and add in my cloud function.
Then i commit & push (successfully)
finally i restart my Heroku server
Then i still get an error 141 invalid function return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have successfully solved this problem and gotten regular queries to work.  The problem was in my Heroku config vars in the dashboard.  My server URL was invalid, never changed from the default of "http://yourappname.com/parse/" I have to manually enter "yourappname".